# alternate for Youtube Api

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

Within my organization YouTube playback service is ban. I can get title, description and all the details about any YouTube video but unable to stream it on my system. Is there any solution that can help without using VPN? any alternate YouTube API?? or Something else. (I just want to avoid that  video playback session that google API generate while streaming any video on client server side )
Any help will be appreciated.

Edited***

I am adding this picture for your understanding  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5vNk.png)

I just don't want this VideoPlayback session thing.

Comment: Maybe I don't get what you mean by "YouTube playback service". Is it just the mechanism for [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/) to be able to stream the video itself to your computer? If so, it seems clear to me that you can't access the video itself without using something similar to a VPN.

Comment: I have added a picture of that thing. if any system is blocked within our organization then this thing become red and video streaming is not possible from YouTube for that system IP.

Comment: "I just don't want this VideoPlayback session thing." however as far as I understand, this `videoplayback` endpoint is used to transmit the videos themselves. So you can't look for the videos and don't want to use the endpoint that YouTube proposes to receive the videos.